# Unmet dependecies—how to fix

Tags: 13.10, dependencies

I have an Ubuntu 13.10 installation, and some I must have removed some Packages or Repositories, so there are some packages which just do not want to install. Namely that is:

**SKYPE**
`sudo apt-get install skype-bin`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype-bin:i386 : Depends: libqtgui4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxss1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxv1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: sni-qt:i386 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Than `nspluginwrapper`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nspluginwrapper : Depends: nspluginviewer (= 1.4.4-0ubuntu5)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And a whole lot of other packages appear if I try to install the shown dependencies. I guess I have delete a whole repository, but how can I figure out which ones are be default in the list?

Thanks in Ahead!

**EDIT**

[here](http://pastebin.com/CHJx4e6X) is a copy of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt-get update` first.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This will attempt to install (yet) unmet dependencies.